# How do I get this basic OOP code to work in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

Thanks for reading my question. I am elaborating a class in which, 3 values must be entered by keyboard, the attributes must be handled with properties, the class must have the constructor and the destructor, and the highest and lowest value must be displayed. I do not know how I should make my code work correctly, for this reason I need help from someone to review it and locate the error. And it shows me compilation error and when testing it and entering the first value, it shows me 'false' on the screen. Some parts are in Spanish, because, they ask me to do so, I hope it is not an inconvenience.

I am attaching my code below, I hope someone can help me thank you.

```vb
Public Class ValoresPorTeclado
        Private Val1 As Integer
        Private Val2 As Integer
        Private Val3 As Integer
        Public Sub New() 'Constructor 
            Dim p = Val1 And Val1 AndAlso Val3 = 0
        End Sub
        Protected Shared Sub Finalize() 'Destructor
        End Sub
        Public Property Valor() As Integer
            Get
                Return Valor
            End Get
            Set(ByVal num As Integer)
                If num > 0 Then
                    Dim p = Val1 And Val2 AndAlso Val3 = num
                ElseIf num < 0 Then
                    Dim p = Val1 And Val2 AndAlso Val3 = num
                Else
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Sub CargarValores(valor As Integer)
            Dim v As Integer
            Console.Write("Ingrese el primer valor ")
            v = Console.ReadLine()
            valor = Val1
            Console.Write("Ingrese el segundo valor")
            valor = Val2
            Console.Write("Ingrese el tercer valor")
            valor = Val3
            CargarValores(valor)
        End Sub
        Public Sub Calcular(ByVal v As Integer)
            Dim f, Compare As Integer
            For f = 1 To 100
                Compare = f > v AndAlso f < v
                Dim Comapare As Boolean = Nothing
                Console.Write(Comapare)
                Console.Write("-")
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        End Sub
    End Class
    Sub Main()
        Dim Valores As New ValoresPorTeclado()
        Valores.CargarValores()
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Did you mean Object-oriented programming OOP?

Comment: Oh sorry yeah I'll change it right now

Answer (score 4):

There are so many errors that it is hard to tell you how to fix them.

You should start by setting

```vb
Option Strict On
```

at the top of your code or in the project properties. This generates even more compiling errors. This is good, because it often reveals errors in your code that prevent it from running right.

---

There is an `End Module` without matching `Module moduleName`. Write

```vb
Module Program
    Sub Main()
        ...
    End Sub
End Module
```

---

The constructor declares a local variable `p`. This variable is only accessible in the constructor itself and is therefore useless.

---

I know, you have been told to do so, but finalizers in .NET are not a good idea unless there is a compelling reason for them, like releasing resources. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors) for C# sharp says (the same is true for VB):

> Empty finalizers should not be used. When a class contains a finalizer, an entry is created in the Finalize queue. When the finalizer is called, the garbage collector is invoked to process the queue. An empty finalizer just causes a needless loss of performance.

---

`Property Valor` makes no sense.

- It returns itself in the getter, thus leading to an endless recursion.
- The setter makes the difference between two cases `num > 0` and `num < 0`, but the two cases then do exactly the same.
- The two cases in the setter declare and initialize a local variable that is never used.
- The condition `Val1 And Val2 AndAlso Val3 = num` is wrong. It should probably be `Val1 = num And Val2 = num  And Val3 = num` (but I do not see what its purpose is in this context).
- Either use `And` or the short circuiting version `AndAlso`. Mixing the two makes no sense.

Since I have no idea what the intention of this property is, I cannot tell you how to fix it.

`Sub CargarValores` has an unused Integer parameter. It is useless. You have only one `ReadLine()`. How is it supposed to read 3 values from the user? You assign `Val1`, `Val2` and `Val3` to `valor`. Instead, you should assign the values you read from the user to `Val1`, `Val2` and `Val3`.

`CargarValores` calls itself at the end, thus again creating an endless recursion.

---

You wrote *"3 values must be entered by keyboard, the attributes must be handled with properties"*, but you have declared 3 fields instead. Make them properties.

---

Trying to put things together.

Declare the class as

```vb
Option Strict On

Public Class ValoresPorTeclado
    Public Property Val1 As Integer
    Public Property Val2 As Integer
    Public Property Val3 As Integer

    ... the methods go here
End Class
```

Since you must input 3 values, declare a function prompting the user, reading the input as string and converting this input into an integer

```vb
Private Function PromptForValue(prompt As String) As Integer
    Console.Write(prompt + ": ")
    Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
    Return Integer.Parse(input)
End Function
```

This function can be used in `Sub CargarValores` to load the 3 values and set the properties

```vb
Public Sub CargarValores()
    Val1 = PromptForValue("Ingrese el primer valor")
    Val2 = PromptForValue("Ingrese el segundo valor")
    Val3 = PromptForValue("Ingrese el tercer valor")
End Sub
```

You must get the lowest and the highest values. Create functions for this

```vb
Public Function LowestValue() As Integer
    Dim lowest As Integer = Val1

    If Val2 < lowest Then
        lowest = Val2
    End If

    If Val3 < lowest Then
        lowest = Val3
    End If

    Return lowest
End Function

Public Function HighestValue() As Integer
    Dim highest As Integer = Val1

    If Val2 > highest Then
        highest = Val2
    End If

    If Val3 > highest Then
        highest = Val3
    End If

    Return highest
End Function
```

Now you can write the `Main` method as

```vb
Module Program
    Sub Main()
        Dim Valores As New ValoresPorTeclado()

        Valores.CargarValores()

        Dim lowest As Integer = Valores.LowestValue()
        Dim highest As Integer = Valores.HighestValue()

        Console.WriteLine($"The lowest value is {lowest}")
        Console.WriteLine($"The highest value is {highest}")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Constructor and destructor can be left empty. If it was not a requirement in your assigment, I would drop them.

Comment: Omg I appreciate it too much, it was certainly very clear to me, thank you very much!!!!!!!!

Comment: Did you intend for `PromptForValue` to be part of the class? This would tie the class to a Console application. I thought classes should be independent from the user interface.

Comment: @Mary, yes they should be inserted where I wrote *"... the methods go here"* in the class `ValoresPorTeclado`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your class independent from the user interface.
As previously stated your code was a bit of a mess.

This simple class contains 2 constructors, 3 properties and a single method.

The parametrized constructor sets all three properties. We add back the default constructor so an application using the class can set properties individually if it wishes.

The `Function` returns the highest of the 3 Properties by using the `.Max` method of
`List(Of T)`.

```
Public Class ValoresPorTeclado
    Public Property Valor1 As Integer
    Public Property Valor2 As Integer
    Public Property Valor3 As Integer

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(Int1 As Integer, Int2 As Integer, Int3 As Integer) 'Constructor 
        Valor1 = Int1
        Valor2 = Int2
        Valor3 = Int3
    End Sub

    Public Function GetMaxInteger() As Integer
        Dim ListOfValues As New List(Of Integer)
        ListOfValues.AddRange({Valor1, Valor2, Valor3})
        Return ListOfValues.Max
    End Function
End Class
```

To use the class in a Console application...

We are using the `Integer.TryParse` which returns `True` or `False` and also sets the value of `i` to the converted string if it returns `True`.

After we get the user input we create a new instance of the `ValoresPorTeclado` class calling the parametrized constructor. Then we can call the `Function` on this instance, `val`.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Counter As Integer
        Dim IntegerList As New List(Of Integer)
        Do Until Counter = 3
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number")
            Dim i As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, i) Then
                IntegerList.Add(i)
                Counter += 1
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number. Try again.")
            End If
        Loop
        Dim val As New ValoresPorTeclado(IntegerList(0), IntegerList(1), IntegerList(2))
        Console.WriteLine($"The highest number you entered is {val.GetMaxInteger}")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```